# What's the difference between "export -p" and "env" commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

`env` displays a list of all environment variables

```
$ env |wc -l
63
```

Total environment variables = 63

According to `help export`

```
-p   display a list of all exported variables and functions

$export -p |wc -l 
63
```

Environment variables+lines of functions=63   then lines of functions=0

`set` disply a list of environment variables+ shell variables+functions

```
$set |wc -l
4772
```

Then for showing only variables(environment variables+shell variables)

```
$(set -o posix ;set)|wc -l
172
```

It means lines of functions= 4772-172 not zero
please explain to me what's happening?

Comment: Each function spans multiple lines, counting number of lines is plain wrong. Also i don't understand what is tripping you up here if you know the difference between environment variable and shell variable.

Comment: I want to know why the result of `export -p` and `env` are the same! it means ,we have no functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion arises from the fact that `export -p` by default only shows exported *variables* (`declare -x`), not *functions*.

To display the exported *functions* (`declare -fx`) using `export`:

```
export -fp
```

Also just to clarify, counting number of lines to get number of functions is completely wrong as function definitions span multiple lines (even if it defined in a single line while declaring, `set` shows them in multiple lines).

Comment: thanks,why in ´help export´ write like that?

Comment: @Sinoosh Hmmmm, i wonder too. I will dig deeper when i get a chance.